# Getting node's text in PHP DOM

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

How could I extract the string "text" from this markup using the PHP DOM?

```
<div><span>notthis</span>text</div>
```

`$div->nodeValue` includes "notthis"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So long as you can affect the DOM, you could remove that `span`.

```
$span = $div->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0);
$div->removeChild($span);

$nodeValue = $div->nodeValue;
```

Alternatively, just access the text node of `$div`.

```
foreach($div->childNodes as $node) {

    if ($node->nodeType != XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        continue;
    }
    $nodeValue = $node;
}
```

If you end up with more text nodes and only want the first, you can `break` after the first assignment of `$nodeValue`.

Answer (score 42):

You can access `DOMText` node directly using XPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom_document);
$node = $xpath->query('//div/text()')->item(0);
echo $node->textContent; // text
```