# xpath Query: only retrieve value of grandchild

Tags: php, xpath

I want to use xpath query to retrieve the "Testing" only once, in the following test.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="test1"></div>
        <div class="test2">
            <div><strong>Testing</strong></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the php code I used to retrieve the content.

```
$uri='test.html';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$doc->loadHTMLFile($uri);
$xpath= new DOMXPath($doc);
$path="/html/body/div[2]//*"; 
$elements = $xpath->query($path);

if(!is_null($elements)){
    foreach($elements as $element){
        echo '<br>['.$element->nodeName.']';
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach($nodes as $node){
            $nodeValue=$node->nodeValue;
            echo $nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result I got.

```
[div] Testing 
[strong] Testing
```

Why does it print "Testing" even in the [div] node? I want it only retrieve "Testing" when it is in [strong] node.

Comment: Because a grandchild would be `/./.`, `//*`== any child at any depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how it works - `nodeValue` of parent node will always contain `nodeValue`s of its children.

`nodeValue` doesn't quite fit your goal. You should get text nodes among its children instead. See this question: [Getting node's text in PHP DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399924/getting-nodes-text-in-php-dom).

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath `/html/body/div[2]//*` returns all descendants of `div[2]` including child and grandchild nodes.

To get only grandchildren use `/html/body/div[2]/*/*`