# Remove anchor tag and get inner text in an array form using regular expression

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I am using this code for removing anchor tag and also to get only inner text using expression

```
    <ul class="alpha">
                <li><h3><a href="http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/Computers-Tablets/473/dept.html?TID=TN:ELEC:Comp">Computers &amp; Tablets</a></h3></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/2-in-1s/28195/subcat.html?TID=TN:ELEC:2in1">2-in-1s</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/Laptops/133/subcat.html?TID=TN:ELEC:Lap">Laptops</a></li>
</ul>
```

Expression is:

```
echo preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $str);
```

Output is:

```
Computers & Tablets
2-in-1s
Laptops
```

Can we get inner text inside anchor tag in an array form using regular expression? Please share your ideas.

Comment: Is it PHP then? You can easily do this with `DOMDocument`.

Comment: instead of `preg_replace` use `preg_match_all`

Comment: As a general rule: use DOM parsing, not regexes to parse HTML.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to process HTML. Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399924/getting-nodes-text-in-php-dom) question to see how it can be done through DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't prefer you to work HTML along with regex instead use DomDocument but as if you want to use regex than you can use `preg_match_all` as

```
preg_match_all('/(?:(<a.*?>))(.*?)(?=<\/a>)/', '<ul class="alpha">
                <li><h3><a href="http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/Computers-Tablets/473/dept.html?TID=TN:ELEC:Comp">Computers &amp; Tablets</a></h3></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/2-in-1s/28195/subcat.html?TID=TN:ELEC:2in1">2-in-1s</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/Laptops/133/subcat.html?TID=TN:ELEC:Lap">Laptops</a></li>
</ul>',$res);
print_r($res[0]);
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Computers & Tablets
    [1] => 2-in-1s
    [2] => Laptops
)
```

Comment: A regex-based solution for parsing an HTML string containing `.*?` is far from being perfect. I am sure you will come back here sooner than later for a reliable, right solution. Just a couple of examples: [Bad 1](https://regex101.com/r/vJ2yC6/1), [Bad 2](https://regex101.com/r/vJ2yC6/2). Once the input string is large enough, catastrophic backtracking is imminent.

Comment: Yes you're right @stribizhev even that's why I've said its not good idea to work along with regex with HTML its not the correct way to deal with HTML parsing

Answer (score 0):

Since you used a jQuery tag I'd prefer to do this in jQuery:

```
var values = [];
$('.alpha').find('a').each(function(index){
    values.push($(this).text());
});
```

This code gets all the links in the .alpha class and pushes them in the `values` array. The output of `values` is:

```
0: "Computers & Tablets"
1: "2-in-1s"
2: "Laptops"
```