# PHP regexp (preg_match_all) - find all standalone links

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a text in form of:

```
Txx8xxTT<br><br><br>https://wwww.xxx.com<br><br />
<br />cxyc[link=http://www.example.com]link[/odkaz]
xxx<a href="http://www.example2.com">link2</a>
```

I want to parse this using preg_match_all where in the result array all standalone links are at separate indices. In the example case I want to have something like this:

```
[0] => Txx8xxTT<br><br><br>
[1] => https://wwww.xxx.com
[2] => <br><br />
    <br />cxyc[link=http://www.example.com]link[/odkaz]
    xxx<a href="http://www.example2.com">link2</a>
```

(The array can be formatted differently, I dont care about the indices, but I want the separate links at its own index)

I have tried to use `preg_match_all` with `(.[^ \<\[]*)`. It almost works, but I get the result at index [3] as `<br>https://wwww.xxx.com`, where I dont want the `<br>` prefix.

```
[0] => Txx8xxTT
[1] => <br>
[2] => <br>
[3] => <br>https://wwww.xxx.com
[4] => <br>
[5] => <br
[6] =>  /> 
[7] => <br
[8] =>  />cxyc
[9] => [link="http://www.example.com"]link
[10] => [/odkaz]xxx
[11] => <a
[12] =>  href="http://www.example2.com">link2
[13] => </a>
```

Comment: Don't use regex. It really isn't suited to this task. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3):

Probably best to:

1. Parse your input via a HTML / DOM parser
2. Use DOM / XPath to find your text nodes
3. Extract the URL using regex

An example of 1 and 2 can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6399988/406712

Then for your regex consider a "negative lookbehind" to exclude the link that starts with "[link=":

## Use

```php
preg_match_all('/(?<!\[link=)\bhttps?:\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```

## Regular Expression

```
(?<!\[link=)\bhttps?://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]
```

## Visualisation

[image: Regex Visualization]

PS. if you are going to be modifying the HTML input then use DOM methods to do that.

Answer (score 2):

See my comment above explaining the horror of parsing html with regex. It really isn't the best approach. DOMDocument may be a better idea.

If you just want an array of links, you could try this. I guarantee nothing however.

```
#https?:\/\/[a-z1-9\.]+#
```

This returns:

```
Match 1
Full match  20-40   https://wwww.xxx.com
Match 2
Full match  67-89   http://www.example.com
Match 3
Full match  115-138 http://www.example2.com
```

https://regex101.com/r/Sh5CTa/1

UPDATE
since you dont want href= or link=, you could try this?

```
#>(?<link>https?:\/\/[a-z1-9\.]+)<#
```

It uses a named capture group, so it would be $matches['link']

https://regex101.com/r/Sh5CTa/2

Comment: I donw want all links, only the standalone ones, because I need to wrap them with href and other "decoration". My regexp is working as it should, the only problem is I would like to remove `<br>` from [3]. I can do this with PHP, but it seems that I am missing something in my regex which would be more legenat than using PHP for matches.

Comment: what do you mean by standalone?

Comment: @delboy1978uk standalone link = not inside href or my own [link=]